# How to differentiate between user-initiated and programmatic pager state changes?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a viewmodel function that gets invoked every time a pager's current page changes. I also have a viewmodel state that should make the pager scroll to a specific page. The Compose side looks like this:

```
// Compose
val viewModel = viewModel<...>()
val viewModelPageState by viewModel.pageFlow.collectAsState()
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

// Inform the viewmodel when a page changes
LaunchedEffect(pagerState.currentPage) {
    viewModel.onPageChanged()
}

// React to viewmodel's page changes
LaunchedEffect(viewModelPageState) {
    pagerState.scrollToPage(viewModelPageState)
}
```

However, the issue here is that `onPageChanged()` should only be invoked when the page change is user-initiated. If the page is changed as a result of the viewmodel's state changing, the `onPageChanged()` function should not be invoked. How can I achieve this?